# How to protecting Google Cloud infrastructure against laptop theft and use of gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm reviewing security on my hosting infrastructure, which is based on Google VMs, SQL and Cloud Storage. It seems to be that the following scenario is a risk:

1. I use `gcloud` or `gsutil` on my MacOS laptop, which stores my sign-in
   credentials so that it doesn't ask for them every time I use one of
   these utilities.
2. Someone steals my laptop (very possible)
3. By whatever means, the thief succeeds in signing in as me (less likely, but not
   impossible)
4. The thief can now run `gcloud` or `gsutil` and do more or less whatever damage they want to my web hosting.

This possibility seems plausible to me, and could be a catastrophic.

Can anyone think of a way of a good way to reduce this risk? For example, a way of managing security so that I am challenged to provide credentials whenever my laptop reboots or exits from sleep, but not on every single command?

(I've also asked this question as a support case with Google)

Comment: Could you put the utilities, or their data, in a VeraCrypt-protected folder? You'd only need to enter a password at the start of a session, and can set VeraCrypt to dismount folder on lock screen, log-out, timeout, etc. You could also keep a keyfile on a USB, use it and immediately unplug it.

Answer (score 2):

If someone knows your login password, they've got your entire keychain, bank details … everything.

Filevault & the security T2 chipset boot options are your main security for the entire Mac. Also, ensure FindMy is enabled. That will prevent any attempt to wipe it. Make sure they're enabled & your AFK timeout is short enough to not be a risk.
If you have TouchID, you can just press the button as you walk away & the machine will lock immediately, otherwise use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Q</kbd>

It should already ask you for credentials every time it's been asleep or rebooted, unless you set auto-login.

Use a good password strategy for your login. Then you don't need to worry about the rest. You cannot brute-force a modern Mac.

Unless…

[image]

Under [xkcd license](https://xkcd.com/license.html) - https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/security.png

Answer (score 2):

Having now spoken to Google support, the recommended way of protecting against this is the following command:

```
gcloud auth revoke --all
```

This revokes permissions on the `gcloud` and `gsutils` utilities. Before using them again, you need to do a

```
gcloud login
```

This opens a browser window for you to sign in to your Google account and enable the utilities to be used once more.

If you have more than one account in use, skip the `--all` and revoke just the account you need. You can find the list of active accounts using:

```
gcloud auth list
```